# Can you help me C# switch case

Tags: c#, switch-statement, case

I have code C# switch case

```
public void gdvDetail_CustomUnboundColumnData(object sender, DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Base.CustomColumnDataEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        DataRowView oRow = (DataRowView)(gdvDetail.GetRow(e.ListSourceRowIndex));
        switch (e.Column.Name)
        {
            case colQuotaQuantity.Name:
                if (colQuotaQuantity.UnboundExpression == "" && oRow.Row.Table.Columns.Contains("QuotaQuantity"))
                {
                    e.Value = oRow.Row["QuotaQuantity"];
                }
                break;
                //e.Value = oRow.Row("Quantity")
            case colDifferenceQuantity.Name:
                if (oRow.Row.Table.Columns.Contains("QuotaQuantity") && !Information.IsDBNull(oRow.Row["QuotaQuantity"]) && !Information.IsDBNull(oRow.Row["Quantity"]))
                {
                    e.Value = System.Convert.ToDouble(oRow.Row["Quantity"]) - System.Convert.ToDouble(oRow.Row["QuotaQuantity"]);
                }
                break;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        CommonFunction.ShowExclamation(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

When I try to compile the application, I receive the following errors:

> A constant value is expected
>   line : case colQuotaQuantity.Name:
>   line : case colDifferenceQuantity.Name:

Can you help me?

Comment: Put yourself into the shoes of the compiler: if you are asked to separate the cases and you get pointer (`colQuotaQuantity.Name`) which can point to several cases, than you would need an extra switch case to handle all those possible cases. Therefore it wants a **constant** value

Answer (score 1):

The values in a `switch/case` statement have to be **compile-time constants**, like numeric values or string literals:

```
switch(i)
{
    case 0: /*...*/ break;
    case 1: /*...*/ break;
}

switch(s)
{
    case "hello": /*...*/ break;
    case "world": /*...*/ break;
}
```

You **cannot use variables** as their value is only known at *run-time*, but not at *compile time*. So `case colDifferenceQuantity.Name:` is not valid in C#.

You will to convert this code to `if` statements:

```
if (e.Column.Name == colQuotaQuantity.Name)
{
    /* ... */
}
else if (e.Column.Name == colDifferenceQuantity.Name)
```